# Windows rsync command line

Tags: windows, command-line, file-synchronization

I'm trying to implement remote delta compression for a game updater and have trouble finding a Windows alternative to rsync for patching updpated files.

My problem with other implementations I found is that:

- they don't have the possibility to call them from command line. As far as I know they all force us to use their GUI.
- they need cygwin or an installation. I would like a little portable batch file or something that would be easy to call from my updater (C# / Unity3d).
- they look like an alternative but they're not (robocopy …).

I can't find nothing useful so maybe I'm taking the problem from the wrong end.

Comment: Do you have a budget in mind? If not, please add the [tag:gratis] tag

Comment: Well I can pay if no free alternatives are found. I made a little script to compare the hash of each file and download them if necessary. Works well (files not too large for the moment) until I find better. I found some projects using signature diff algorithms similar to rsync, will test them when I work on this again

Comment: That sounds good. I was just giving a gentle "welcome on board" reminder that seems to need to be given to most (no offence intended). At least you stated an operating system, you would be surprised at how many do not.  The second most important thing is to use the [tag:gratis] tag - which can exclude a lot of possible answers - or state a budget. The general idea is that the more detailed information the poster can give us, the more that we can help to give a tailored answer. I think/hope that is stated in [ask]. Anyway welcome on board; I hope that we can help you, & that you can help others